# rotate Canvas within a Grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am able to rotate a canvas fine using LayoutTransform. But the corners go out of the Grid width or height. How can I rotate and resize the canvas to keep it inside the Grid.
Here is how I am rotating :-

```
    private void btnRotate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (RotationAngle == 360)
        {
            RotationAngle = 0;
        }
        RotationAngle = RotationAngle + 1;

        RotateTransform rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
        rotateTransform.Angle = RotationAngle;
        TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
        transformGroup.Children.Add(rotateTransform);
        rotateTransform.CenterX = 0.5;
        rotateTransform.CenterY = 0.5;
        cnvsYardMap.LayoutTransform = transformGroup;   
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Grid` cannot accommodate the new size of it's child `Canvas`, then it's expected to overflow the bounds.

so if you have something like:

```
<Grid Height="200">
  <Canvas x:Name="blah"
          Width="280"
          Height="150"
          Background="Tomato" />
</Grid>
```

and you apply a 50deg `LayoutTransform`, this will indeed overflow.

For what you're trying, you could wrap the `Canvas` in a [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx). So something like:

```
<Grid Height="200">
  <Viewbox>
    <Canvas x:Name="blah"
            Width="280"
            Height="150"
            Background="Tomato" />
  </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Now applying the same transform will **"appear"** to shrink the `Canvas` size to fit it within the parent `Grid`. Do note that the `Viewbox` scales it's children than resize them, so it's just a visual effect. The `Width` and `Height` of the `Canvas` will still remain what it originally was before the transform.

Answer (score 0):

You have the [ClipToBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx) property that 'crops' the content of a children :

Normal behavior :

[image]

With ClipToBounds enabled:

[image]

Also, depending your needs you might need a RenderTransform instead :

[image]

(from [LayoutTransform vs. RenderTransform – What’s the Difference?](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2008/12/layouttransform-vs-rendertransform-whats-the-difference/))